# R/ggplot2 - Overlapping labels on facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, histogram, overlapping

Folks,

I am plotting histograms using geom_histogram and I would like to label each histogram with the mean value (I am using mean for the sake of this example). The issue is that I am drawing multiple histograms in one facet and I get labels overlapping. This is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame (type=rep(1:2, each=1000), subtype=rep(c("a","b"), each=500), value=rnorm(4000, 0,1))
plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x=value, fill=subtype)) + geom_histogram(position="identity", alpha=0.4)
plt <- plt +  facet_grid(. ~ type)
plt + geom_text(aes(label = paste("mean=", mean(value)), colour=subtype, x=-Inf, y=Inf), data = df, size = 4, hjust=-0.1, vjust=2)
```

Result is:

[image: This is the result I get]

The problem is that the labels for Subtypes a and b are overlapping. I would like to solve this.

I have tried the position, both dodge and stack, for example:

```
plt + geom_text(aes(label = paste("mean=", mean(value)), colour=subtype, x=-Inf, y=Inf), position="stack", data = df, size = 4, hjust=-0.1, vjust=2)
```

This did not help. In fact, it issued warning about the width.

Would you pls help ?
Thx,
Riad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could precalculate mean values before plotting in new data frame.

```
library(plyr)
df.text<-ddply(df,.(type,subtype),summarise,mean.value=mean(value))

df.text
  type subtype   mean.value
1    1       a -0.003138127
2    1       b  0.023252169
3    2       a  0.030831337
4    2       b -0.059001888
```

Then use this new data frame in `geom_text()`. To ensure that values do not overlap you can provide two values in `vjust=` (as there are two values in each facet).

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=value, fill=subtype)) + 
  geom_histogram(position="identity", alpha=0.4)+
  facet_grid(. ~ type)+
  geom_text(data=df.text,aes(label=paste("mean=",mean.value),
                 colour=subtype,x=-Inf,y=Inf), size = 4, hjust=-0.1, vjust=c(2,4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt answer. That's exactly what I am looking for ! Riad.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on @Didzis:

You actually have two problems here. First, the text overlaps, but more importantly, when you use aggregating functions in `aes(...)`, as in:

```
geom_text(aes(label = paste("mean=", mean(value)), ...
```

`ggplot` does not respect the subsetting implied in the facets (or in the groups for that matter). So `mean(value)` is based on the full dataset regardless of faceting or grouping. As a result, you *have to* use an auxillary table, as @Didzis shows.

BTW:

```
df.text <- aggregate(df$value,by=list(type=df$type,subtype=df$subtype),mean)
```

gets you the means and does not require `plyr`.

Comment: Great explanation, I now understand why I was getting the same number in all the facets. BTW, I went for the plyr base solution as I needed to calculate the quantiles: `df.text<-ddply(df,.(type,subtype),summarise,mean=mean(value),sd=sd(value),Q0027=quantile(value,0.0027,names=F)) `. Thx again for your comments, very much appreciated