# Stop labels in ggplot2 from overlapping R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been searching for most of the day so far to find a way to stop labels from overlapping each other but I can't find an adequate solution. The closest i have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359820/r-ggplot2-overlapping-labels-on-facet-grid) example on stack overflow, but using that method i get the below error

```
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:c(2, 4)
```

[image]

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/

Comment: Sometimes you can just get away with `... + geom_text(... position = "jitter")`. But this only works when there's only a couple of clusters. Also, it might be nice to colour your points the same as your labels.